# JPanel titled border with tooltip text for the title

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, tooltip, border

I am using `setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title))` in my `JPanel` in order to group its content in a rectangle with a title above it. How can I set a tooltip text for the title?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `getToolTipText()` method of the panel to check if the mouse of over the title text:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TitledBorderTest
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        UIManager.getDefaults().put("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.RED);
        Border lowerEtched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);
        TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lowerEtched, "Title");
//      title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.RIGHT);
        Font titleFont = UIManager.getFont("TitledBorder.font");
        title.setTitleFont( titleFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD) );

        JPanel panel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Border border = getBorder();

                if (border instanceof TitledBorder)
                {
                    TitledBorder tb = (TitledBorder)border;
                    FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics( tb.getTitleFont() );
                    int titleWidth = fm.stringWidth(tb.getTitle()) + 20;
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, titleWidth, fm.getHeight());
                    return bounds.contains(e.getPoint()) ? super.getToolTipText() : null;
                }

                return super.getToolTipText(e);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder( title );
        panel.setToolTipText("Title With ToolTip");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code assumes the title is on the left. If you want the title on the right then you would need to adjust the `X` value of the text bounds.

Comment: Thanks. The idea works for me. I think it imposes setting fonts for the title, but never mind. I can instead use the full top strip of the border as the bounds for showing the tooltip.

Comment: @HamidFadishei, just use getFont() and you will get the panel font, which is the default Font for the titled border.

Comment: I think both are good ideas, but now hearing Hamid Fadishei say that he was going to use the full border as the text, I'm inclined to say I like that idea more. This way, the user doesn't have to hover over just the text itself, the entire border will tell the user what is inside of that JComponent.

Answer (score 6):

A possible approach is nesting components. As Borders are not components they can not have tooltips, but you can have a component with the sole purpose of holding border and the tooltip:

```
JPanel outer = new JPanel();
outer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"));
outer.setToolTipText("sample text");
JPanel inner = new JPanel();
outer.add(inner);
```

and then use `inner` as the container for the components you want to group.

Comment: can u tell me the use of tooltiptext, We can add tittle from second line of code only , whats the use of tool tip here??

Comment: @Sushantp606 ask the person who asked the question. The request was to add a tool tip to the border.(Or more strictly, to the title, like camickrs answer does).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add `setToolTipText` to `TitledBorder`. you can provide tooltip for `JComponent` but `TitledBorder` is not derived from `JComponent`.

You can try to use `JPanel` instead:

```
 ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(new JPanel());
 //ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(800000);
```

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative approaches to group UI components in a border with a title that has a tooltip text?

Comment: I don't know how to use your suggestion to reach the goal stated in my question. Maybe it's concise and I'm too novice in Swing to get the point!

Comment: My point is instead to add tooltip to border, because you can't, botder is not `JComponent`, create `JPanel` into other `JPanel` and add tooltip to internal `JPanel`. But user will fill that tooltip goes up like for Border

Answer (score 1):

- TollTip isn't right Components for experiments, all goog workaround for popup or  tooltips are based on JWindow/ undecorated JDialog
- maybe not necessary, keys in UIManager are accesible, but in this case all TollTips has the same settings

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class ColoredToolTipExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ColoredToolTipExample() {
        Border line, raisedbevel, loweredbevel, title, empty;
        line = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("");
        empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Border compound;
        compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty, line);
        UIManager.put("ToolTip.foreground", new ColorUIResource(Color.red));
        UIManager.put("ToolTip.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow));
        UIManager.put("ToolTip.font", new FontUIResource(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18)));
        UIManager.put("ToolTip.border", new BorderUIResource(compound));
        JButton button = new JButton("Hello, world");
        button.setToolTipText("<html> - myText <br> - myText <br> - myText <br>");
        getContentPane().add(button);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colored ToolTip Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ColoredToolTipExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```